# How can I create a Cocoa application without storyboards or interface builders in XCode?

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I just want to be able to create my program ... programmatically. So I went to `File > New > Project` and selected `Cocoa Application`, and ensured that "Use Storyboards" was not checked on the next step of the wizard. The project that it gave me has a `MainMenu.xib` file in it. I don't know what `.xib` files are, but I know that they mess with my program in ways I don't understand.

So how do I create a new Cocoa Application without any of these "storyboard" or "interface builder" things? What is the minimal, purely programmatic, program which launches one empty window?

Comment: Just so you know that Xcode isn't lying to you, .xib files aren't storyboards.  (The **are** interface builder things, though.)

Comment: @PhillipMills oh okay, thanks. I don't know the difference, although I don't want those interface builder files either.

Comment: @jameshfisher Good for you. I do everything in code as well (though for iOS). I don't like all of the hidden magic. When it's all code I know exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 5):

The first question to answer is: Why? Even a basic `MainMenu.xib` does a lot of work for you: Creating the application's menu bar and allowing you to easily set the application delegate, among other functions. You can use that very basic `MainMenu.xib` file and still create everything else (windows, etc.) manually if you want.

If you really do want to avoid using `.xib` files entirely, you can, but doing so requires some intimate knowledge of Cocoa.

Firstly, a Cocoa application's `main` function looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);
}
```

That is, it simply calls Cocoa's `NSApplicationMain` function.

According to the [`NSApplication` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/), `NSApplicationMain()` essentially does this:

```
void NSApplicationMain(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"myMain" owner:NSApp];
    [NSApp run];
}
```

Now, if you're not using `.xib` files at all, you want to avoid loading `MainMenu.xib` entirely, so you'll want to edit the default `main()` function to do something more like this:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    [NSApp setDelegate:[[YourDelegate alloc] init]];
    [NSApp run];
    return 0;
}
```

And then `YourDelegate` will take care of creating the main application menu, windows, etc.

Comment: I tried that earlier today out of curiosity and got a crash.  Now that I look at it in your answer, I realize that the delegate needs to be held by a strong reference somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The basic application you have can be used as a start. You can remove the Menu.xib and launch the application. In your AppDelegate `applicationDidFinishLaunching` you can create programmatically a NSWindowController and your NSMenu. Nevertheless you will have to do many things manually that come out of the box with xib or storyboard.